# Can not generate service, versioning conflict. What could I broke?

Tags: feathersjs

I use feathers for some months now and I already created and used several services. The app is generated with feather/cli command: 'feathers generate app'.

Today I tried to generate a new service with the usual command:
`feathers generate service`
only to get the error:

`× This version of the generator will only work with Feathers Buzzard (v3) and up. Please run`feathers upgrade`first.`

Fine. Run the upgrade. Got new error:

`throw new Error('It looks like`@feathersjs/feathers`is already a dependency. I can not run the upgrade again.');
    ^`

- checked the version: is 3.9.0
- Uninstalled/re-installed feathers/cli
  Nothing works. Not sure what I broke as I did not (remember to) upgrade anything since a couple of days ago when I created the last service. Feathers was not updated in the last 4 months.

I tried googling my error but it seems like nobody else has this problem so it has to be something I've done.

Any suggestions?

LE: I have in package.json dependencies:

````
    "@feathersjs/errors": "^3.3.6",
    "@feathersjs/express": "^1.3.1",
    "@feathersjs/feathers": "^3.3.1",
    "@feathersjs/socketio": "^3.2.9",
    "feathers-knex": "^5.0.7",
    "feathers-memory": "^3.0.2",
    "feathers-rest": "^1.8.1",
    "feathers": "^2.2.4",```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will be shown if you still have the `feathers` module in your `dependencies` in your `package.json`. If `@feathersjs/feathers` is already included as well you can just remove the `feathers` dependency (after making sure it is not used anywhere else in your application which it shouldn't).

Comment: Hi Daff, thanks for taking the time to reply and help me.
I've update the post with my dependencies which regards feathers because in comment the format is not so readable. Should I delete only feathers or all of them?

Comment: This works! For those who have the same problem: remove from package-lock.json dependencies as well any reference to `@feathersjs/feathers`